# ФС для хранилища фильмов

Tags: linux

Разделах, к которым не предполагается доступ с других ОС, я обычно форматирую в ext4. Нет ли смысла для раздела только для видео, как для файлов большого объема, использовать более специализированную файловую систему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смысл есть в том случае, когда

1. суммарный размер хранилища велик (больше терабайт),
2. есть специфика доступа (например, редко читается, часто пишется или наоборот),
3. есть специфика файлов (все файлы большие, порядка гигабайт),
4. нужны особые требования по надежности,
5. нужна расширяемость на различные носители,
6. и т.д.

Тогда вполне можно, используя специально заточенную систему (XFS, ZFS, PVFS), получить какие-либо преимущества.

Если объем хранилища небольшой и файлы используются редко, вряд ли смена файловой системы даст существенный выигрыш.